# Adding elements to sublists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `A` containing many sublists. I want to add elements of the previous sublist to the current sublist. For instance, all elements of `A[1]` should be added to `A[0]` to obtain new `A[1]`. Similarly, all elements of `A[2]` should be added to `A[1]` to obtain new `A[2]`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
A=[[0, 0, 0, 0],[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
B=[A[i]+A[i+1] for i in range(0,2)]
print(B)
```

The current output is

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 8, 10, 12]]
```

Comment: You're concatenating two lists, not adding each element of the two lists. You need a nested comprehension here to create new lists within a list.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of `for loop` you can simply compare and check values. You don't need to add a second variable `B` for concatenation.

For that you can use this `code`:

```
A = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

for i in range(1, len(A)):
    A[i] = [A[i][j] + A[i-1][j] for j in range(len(A[i]))]

print(A)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 8, 10, 12]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing the sub-lists are guaranteed to all be of the same size then:

```
A = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

for x, y in zip(A, A[1:]):
    for i in range(len(y)):
        y[i] += x[i]

print(A)
```

This is an *in situ* solution that avoids unnecessary additional list construction.

**Output:**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 8, 10, 12]]
```